# MVC error - The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, ienumerable

I can't figure out what's going on with this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[RepositoryExample.Employee]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'RepositoryExample.Models.IEmployeeManagerRepository'.`

I get the error when I go to the Index view. I added the Index View from the controller but there is no code in it.  I'm using Linq to SQL.

```
@model RepositoryExample.Models.IEmployeeManagerRepository

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

This is my code:

**EmployeeController.cs**

```
    // GET: /Employee/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.ListEmployees());
    }
```

**LinqEmployeeManagerRepository.cs**

```
public class LinqEmployeeManagerRepository: RepositoryExample.Models.IEmployeeManagerRepository
{
    private DeptDirectoryDataClassesDataContext _db = new DeptDirectoryDataClassesDataContext();

    public Employee GetEmployee(string UserName)
    {
        return (from e in _db.Employees where e.UserName == UserName select e).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Employee> ListEmployees()
    {
        return _db.Employees.ToList();
    }

    public Employee CreateEmployee(Employee employeeToCreate)
    {
        _db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(employeeToCreate);
        _db.SubmitChanges();
        return employeeToCreate; 
    }

    public Employee EditEmployee(Employee employeeToEdit)
    { 
        var OriginalEmployee = GetEmployee(employeeToEdit.UserName);
        _db.Employees.Attach(employeeToEdit, OriginalEmployee);
        _db.SubmitChanges();
        return employeeToEdit; 
    }

    public void DeleteEmployee(Employee employeeToDelete)
    {
        var OriginalEmployee = GetEmployee(employeeToDelete.UserName);
        _db.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(OriginalEmployee);
        _db.SubmitChanges();     
    }
}
```

**IEmployeeManagerRepository.cs**

```
namespace RepositoryExample.Models
{
    public interface IEmployeeManagerRepository
    {
        Employee CreateEmployee(Employee employeeToCreate);
        void DeleteEmployee(Employee employeeToDelete);
        Employee EditEmployee(Employee employeeToUpdate);
        Employee GetEmployee(string UserName);
        IEnumerable<Employee> ListEmployees(); 
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to follow the example on Repository pattern in this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/iteration-4-make-the-application-loosely-coupled-cs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the top of your `Index.cshtml` view replace:

```
@model RepositoryExample.Models.IEmployeeManagerRepository
```

with:

```
@model IEnumerable<RepositoryExample.Employee>
```

The `_repository.ListEmployees()` method returns `IEnumerable<Employee>` and that's what you are passing to the view here:

```
return View(_repository.ListEmployees());
```

So that's the type you should be using in the `@model` directive in your view.

Comment: Ok, i did that but now i get a new error:  Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Employee' does not exist in the namespace 'RepositoryExample.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @MikeB55, OK, use the correct namespace where this `Employee` class is defined. `@model IEnumerable<RepositoryExample.Employee>`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you so much. I've been searching for this error for the past 3 hours.  I got it to work now by adding @model IEnumerable<RepositoryExample.Employee> as you suggested.

Comment: @MikeB55, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you should consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: I just did.  Tried before but system told me something about waiting 5 min. before I could do it.